# How to make image opacity respond to cursor position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a cartoon of an antique "detour" sign that has cataphote reflectors embedded in the letters. I want the reflectors to brighten as the image is hovered. That's easily done, I know, simply by swapping out a version of the image with the reflectors darkened with an image of them brightened on hover (per the markup below). However, doing it this way makes the reflectors appear to blink on or off. I want them to get increasingly bright as the cursor nears the center of the image and, of course, dim as the cursor moves away from it, as would occur in real life. (If your headlights beamed at the reflectors at an oblique angle, the light they reflect back would be dimmer than if your headlights hit them straight on.)

My thought is just to increase the opacity of the brightened version of the image in response to the position of the hovering cursor. So, what I need (I think) is a script that detects the cursor position and increases or decreases the opacity accordingly: opacity: 0; at the edge and opacity: 1; at the center. Probably not too challenging for someone adept in javascript/jquery. I've hunted around for a script that does that or something very close to it but haven't been able to locate one that is close enough for me to modify.

I have an additional issue in that in Firefox, at least, the hover image "flicks" the first time it is invoked. I've tried all of the preloading suggestions I could find here on stackoerflow but none of them work. I found that a sprite solved the flicking problem, but wasn't sure how that would work with the way I want the image to animate. Presuming non-sprite images are the way to go maybe if the script invokes the "bright" version of the image at an initial opacity of 0 as the cursor crosses the threshhold, it will also hide the loading "flick...?" Just a guess. Alternatively, I could redesign the hovered version so that it is just the reflectors if that would solve everything else.

Finally, as you can see, the sign is a button that returns a random page. Assuming what I need to solve this problem is a script, can I run both scripts off of the same id (#detour) or should this script use a class name instead? (I am clearly an example of a little knowledge being a dangerous thing.)

Anyway, here's what I've got.

```css
.detour-box {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#detour {
    position: absolute;
    background: transparent url(https://sodyot.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/detour-sign_3.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 100%;
    clip-path: polygon(48% 0%, 49% 1%, 50% 0%, 69% 19%, 81% 31%, 94% 42%, 100% 48%, 100% 49%, 85% 65%, 76% 75%, 63% 88%, 53% 99%, 52% 100%, 48% 97%, 37% 87%, 28% 79%, 16% 67%, 8% 59%, 0 49%, 3% 45%, 14% 35%, 28% 20%);
    width: 300px;
    height: 295px;
 }

#detour:hover {
    background: transparent url(https://sodyot.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/detour-sign_3on.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="detour-box">
    <button id="detour" class="detour" onclick="randomlink()"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: You could get an even more controlled effect by having just one image, with holes punched in where the reflectors are and 'lighting up' from behind. Is altering the image a possibility (just making holes)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we punch holes in the detour sign we only need one image.

The background image can have a linear gradient put behind it, the color(s) of which are changed as the mouse moves. In this snippet the color is always some gray, going up to white, and is changed depending on the y movement of the mouse. It would be easy to change it to take x into account as well. And there could be a real gradient to the background to give different effects - depends just what effect is wanted.

The JS alters a CSS variable, --col, depending on the distance from the center.

```js
  function makeColor(d) {
    d = Math.floor(d);
    return 'rgb(' + d + ',' + d + ',' + d + ')';//could use rgba to get opacity also
  }
  
  const detour = document.getElementById("detour");
  const dimCol = 128;//set this to the initial (switched off) r, g and b gray
  detour.style.setProperty('--col', makeColor(dimCol));
  
  detour.addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
    detour.style.setProperty('--col', makeColor(dimCol));
  });
  
  detour.addEventListener('mousemove', function () {
    const rect = detour.getBoundingClientRect();// this should be in a window resize function if you have one
    const h = rect.height;// ditto
    const y = event.clientY - rect.top; //ditto
    const distanceY = Math.abs(y - h/2)/h;
    const d = 255 * (1 - 2 * distanceY);
    detour.style.setProperty('--col', makeColor(dimCol + (d * (255 - dimCol) / 255)));
  });
```

```css
.detour-box {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

div#detour {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url(https://ahweb.org.uk/detour-with-holes.png), linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0%, transparent 40%, var(--col) 40%, var(--col) 60%, transparent 60%, transparent 100%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: 100%, 70%;
    clip-path: polygon(48% 0%, 49% 1%, 50% 0%, 69% 19%, 81% 31%, 94% 42%, 100% 48%, 100% 49%, 85% 65%, 76% 75%, 63% 88%, 53% 99%, 52% 100%, 48% 97%, 37% 87%, 28% 79%, 16% 67%, 8% 59%, 0 49%, 3% 45%, 14% 35%, 28% 20%);
    width: 300px;
    height: 295px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 }
```

```html
<div class="detour-box">
    <div id="detour" class="detour" onclick="randomlink()"></div>
</div>
```

It is fine to have more than one event listener on an element, so the existing onclick remains.

Comment: I came back to look at this and it looks as though my comment from two days ago never showed up. I'm so sorry for the radio silence. YES. This is genius! I would never have thought to punch holes in the sign, let alone the javascript. Thank you, as always. Yes, I would love for it to work from both directions. Do I just need to replicate the lines in the script that specify a y coordinate and replace it with x, replace "h" with "w" and use "rect.left" where it says "rect.top" now? Or are there other parts I need to add/alter?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to transition from one image to another on the same element by changing the `src` or `background-image` value. But you can do it by having both images, and hiding one by default.

Having one image hidden opens the possibility to fade or crossfade between the images. Lay them on top of each other, with the hidden image on top, and show the hidden image on hover.

The image on top can now fade-in by changing the `opacity` value. With the `transition` property you can control the transition.

```css
.detour-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#detour {
  position: absolute;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 1fr / 1fr;
  clip-path: polygon(48% 0%, 49% 1%, 50% 0%, 69% 19%, 81% 31%, 94% 42%, 100% 48%, 100% 49%, 85% 65%, 76% 75%, 63% 88%, 53% 99%, 52% 100%, 48% 97%, 37% 87%, 28% 79%, 16% 67%, 8% 59%, 0 49%, 3% 45%, 14% 35%, 28% 20%);
  width: 300px;
  height: 295px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#detour img {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#detour img:last-child {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 250ms ease-in-out;
  z-index: 1;
}

#detour:hover img:last-child {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="detour-box">
  <button id="detour" class="detour" onclick="randomlink()">
    <img src="https://sodyot.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/detour-sign_3.png" alt="Detour sign off"/>
    <img src="https://sodyot.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/detour-sign_3on.png" alt="Detour sign on"/>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: I see what you've done and I suspect it would solve the "flicking" issue. I notice, however, that once you are actually on the sign, the reflectors stay at the same brightness no matter where on the sign you are (i.e., at the edge or in the dead center.).